# vb.net list class properties with values

Tags: vb.net, class, properties, tostring

I have a class, and I want to do a custom 'toString' function;

```
Public Class Person
    public property Name as string
    public property Age as interger

    public Overrides Function ToString() as string
         dim BigStr as string = ""
         for each Member as MemberInfo in Me.GetType.GetMembers
               bigst += Member.Name & " " & [thevalue of this instance]
         next
         return BigStr
    end function
end class
```

I want it to automatically display all properties with the value of the current instance. But I don't know how to get the value of property without specifically type it out. Is there a dynamic way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Type.GetMembers` returns a list of `MemberInfo` objects, one per member of the type.  However, not all members have values.  Fields and properties have values, so if you get the list of just the fields or just the properties, you can ask them for their values.  But things like methods don't have a value.  You may be able to invoke them and read their return values, but that's different from reading the value of a property or a field.

In other words, you have to work differently with each member, depending on what kind of member it is.  Since `MemberInfo` is the lowest common-denominator, it doesn't have any of the functionality which only works on *some* of the members.  If you want the additional functionality available to you, you'll need to use one of the more specific methods like `GetProperties` or `GetFields`.

Since your class contains properties, you probably want to get the list of properties:

```
Public Class Person
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Age As Integer

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Dim bigStr As String = ""
        For Each p As PropertyInfo In Me.GetType().GetProperties()
            bigStr &= p.Name & " " & p.GetValue(Me)?.ToString()
        Next
        Return bigStr
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: A small suggestion: I'd recommend using the concatenation assignment operator `&=` instead of the plus assignment operator `+=`.

Comment: @Craig Agreed.  I was just keeping it as close to the original code as possible, only fixing the typos, but you're right.  I should have cleaned it up a bit.  I updated my answer.

Comment: I was looking through this and I don't understand what the ? in the "p.GetValue(Me)?.tostring()" does.  I tried googling but I can't get the search term correct.  Can someone comment and let me know please ?

Comment: @FredKerber Its official name is the "null-conditional member access" operator.  It evaluates the expression to null if the object is null, rather than throwing a `NullReferenceException`.  In this case, it causes nothing to be concatenated to the string if `p.GetValue(Me)` returns `Nothing`.